# I can not connect to Mikrotik RB 3011 router board over 8291 port

Tags: networking, router, mikrotik-routeros

I am trying to configure a brand new **Mikrotik RB 3011** router board and **winbox** can not connect to the router and displays this error message

> ERROR: could not connect to 192.168.1.3

the router is assigned IP "**192.168.1.3**". I can ping the IP "**192.168.1.3**" or the router and I receive the response. but when I call

> telnet 192.168.1.3 8291

the connection failed.

there is no firewall enable on the network

how should I resolve the issue

Comment: Connect by MAC. Enable access via IP (IP-Services).

Comment: @Akina thanks for your comment, connecting by MAC also results the same error. I think port 8291 is closed on router side even after hard reset. I don't know what to do though.